# Concatenate JSON in loop RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, firebase

I would like to concatenate JSON results in one query and save it directly to Firebase.

When I try something like this everything works fine:

```
        getData = RestClient.get 'https://exampleapi.com/api/?page=1'
        getData2 = RestClient.get 'https://exampleapi.com/api/?page=2'
        dataToObj = JSON.parse(getData.body)
        dataToObj2 = JSON.parse(getData2.body)
        results = dataToObj['results'] + dataToObj2['results']
        firebase.push("results", results)
```

but I have 20 pages and I tried to use for loop and it does not work:

```
      for i in 1..20 do
          url = 'https://exampleapi.com/api/?page='
          link = url + i.to_s
          getData = RestClient.get link
          dataToObj = JSON.parse(getData.body) 
          results = dataToObj['results']
          save += results
      end
          firebase.push("results", save)
```

Is there a possibility to make this that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where `save` is defined.  Assuming `dataToObj['results']` is an array, you can initialize `save` to an empty array first; do...

```
save = []
(1..20).each do |i|
  get_data = RestClient.get "https://exampleapi.com/api/?page=#{i}"
  save += JSON.parse(get_data.body)['results']
end
firebase.push("results", save)
```

Comment: That's amazing... Thank you very much!